# Phonegap - OneSignal Push Notifications - app restarting whenever user taps on notification

Tags: cordova, push-notification, onesignal

Alrighty... got a phonegap app that I am setting up to use push notifications using OneSignal. I have it all initialized and I can send test notifications just fine.

When I am testing on my Android device (Galaxy S6) the push comes through but when I tap on the notification it always loads the app fresh even if I already have it opened but is not the focus. Not sure what I am doing that makes the app load each and every time.

Also worth noting, when the app is loaded fresh the handleNotificationReceived function never gets called so I can't respond to it.

Don't think it is my init code, but here it is just in case.

```
function InitializePushNotifications() {
    if (!_isNative)
        return;

    LogInfo('Initializing Push Notifications...');

    var iosSettings = {};
    iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt"] = true;
    iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL"] = false;

    window.plugins.OneSignal
        .startInit(config.Push, config.Google)
        .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
        .iOSSettings(iosSettings)
        .handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonData) {
            LogInfo('PUSH!: ' + jsonData.payload.title + " | " + jsonData.payload.body);
        })
        .handleNotificationOpened(function(jsonData) {
            ShowMySpecialScreen();
        })
        .endInit();
}
```

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**
From a request in the comments, here are the plugins we are currently using:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="1.1.2" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="1.0.3" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="1.2.1" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="4.2" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="1.5.1" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="3.2.2" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" source="npm" spec="2.0.10" />
<gap:plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" source="npm" version="6.0.0">
    <param name="BILLING_KEY" value="KEY GOES HERE" />
</gap:plugin>
```

---

Comment: You are using PhoneGap Build (PGB) and not CLI? Can you add the full list of plugins from your `config.xml`? Other plugins can effect how your app's main `Activity` is started.

Comment: @jkasten Updated original post!

Answer (score 0):

Check your `config.xml` to make sure you haven't set `AndroidLaunchMode`. This must be left default which is `singleTop`. This prevents a 2nd Android `Activity` from being created when a notification is opened.

Comment: Hey there! Just double checked... I have not set the AndroidLaunchMode to anything which, I assume, means that it is the default.